# Summation over diagonal blocks

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have generated a 12*12 matrix with

```
m = RandomInteger[{2, 5}, {12, 12}];
```

but I don't know how I can sum blocks on the main diagonal of the matrix such as:

[image]

It means the final results must be as

```
finalmatrix={{13,10,15},{13,11,15},{14,15,17}}
```

Comment: Is your matrix always square, and is the dimension of the matrix always divisible by the block size and the number of blocks?

Comment: Yes the dimension of the matrix is divisible by blocks. Maybe 36*36 that should be 6 blocks of 6*6 and so on

Comment: You're going to have to set pretty specific rules if you want an answer. There's no obvious rule that says $12\times 12$ should be divided into $4^2$ blocks and $36\times 36$ in $6^2$ blocks.

Comment: @Feyre, unfortunately I cannot understand what you mean. 36*36=6*6*6*6*6*6 row and 6*6*6*6*6*6 column

Comment: I'm just saying the number of blocks you want to divide into between  $12\times 12$ and $36\times 36$ seems arbitrary.

Comment: the dimensions are arbitrary

Comment: yes I made a mistake so sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[blockPlus]
blockPlus = Tr[Partition[#, {#2, #2}], Plus, 2] &;

SeedRandom[1]
m = RandomInteger[{2, 5}, {12, 12}];
m // Grid[#, Dividers -> {#, #} &@Thread[Range[1, 13, 3] -> True]] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
blockPlus[m, 3]
```

> {{14, 13, 10}, {14, 14, 12}, {12, 12, 11}}

```
blockPlus[m, 4]
```

> {{12, 10, 11, 10}, {6, 9, 10, 9}, {12, 9, 6, 11}, {12, 10, 13, 12}}

```
blockPlus[m, 2]
```

> {{18, 21}, {19, 21}}

Comment: Besides so much thanks for your answer but I should ask that I have learnt for a function we must define such as f[x_]:=......... in `blockPlus` which is a function you did not define such as blockPlus[matrix_,n_] but at the below of that you put blockPlus[m,3] or so on! I cannot understand how this work can do

Comment: @Irr: `blockPlus = Tr[Partition[#, {#2, #2}], Plus, 2] &;` is equivalent to `blockPlus[mat_, k_] := Tr[Partition[mat, {k, k}], Plus, 2]`. Look up pure functions.

Comment: O my god, yes you used # and & it deals with pure functions.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps Partition is helpful here?

```
mat = RandomReal[{-1., 1.}, {10, 10}];
```

say you want to sum up diagonal 2 by 2 blocks

```
Total@Diagonal@Partition[mat, {2, 2}]
```

Comment: Works though perhaps set up for `{3,3}` since that is what he asked.

Answer (score 3):

To add desired diagonal block of square matrix (condition for complete blocks):

```
mat[matr_, n_] := 
 Total[matr[[#1 ;; #2, #1 ;; #2]] & @@@ 
    NestList[# + n &, {1, n}, Length[matr[[1]]]/n - 1]] /; 
  IntegerQ[Length[matr[[1]]]/n]
mat[matr_, n_] := "incomplete"
```

"Cosmetics":

```
func[ma_, n_] := 
 Grid[ma, Dividers -> Table[{{True}~Join~Table[False, n - 1]}, 2], 
   Background -> {None, 
     None, {##, ##} -> LightBlue & /@ 
      NestList[# + n &, {1, n}, Length[ma[[1]]]/n - 1]}] /; 
  IntegerQ[Length[ma[[1]]]/n]
vis[matrix_, n_] := 
 Row[{func[matrix, n] -> 
    Grid[mat[matrix, n], Frame -> True, Background -> LightBlue]}]
```

Test matrix:

```
RandomSeed[1];
m = RandomInteger[{2, 5}, {12, 12}];
```

Visualization:

```
Grid[Partition[vis[m, #] & /@ Divisors[12], 2], Alignment -> Left, 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]